# обратное преобразование Фурье ifft Python

Tags: python, fft

Провожу преобразование Фурье

```
FFT = np.fft.fft(input)
```

Перевожу комплексное число в вещественную.

```
FFT_real = FFT.real
```

Провожу обратное преобразование Фурье ifft.

```
iFFT = np.fft.ifft(FFT_real).real.astype(dtype=np.float64)
```

Что делать с мнимой составляющей?
Зелёный график - оригинальный сигнал. Оранжевый - сигнал после обратного преобразования Фурье.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где картинки? :)

Comment: они не нужны, но если запустить алгоритм, они появятся и будет проигрываться звук микрофона. Он отличается от оригинала

Comment: И всё же хорошо бы прикрепить картинки сюда, мало кто захочет разбираться по описанию картинок

Comment: Какой смысл в манипуляциях с комплесным спектром? Почему не взять модуль комплексного числа - амплитуду?

Comment: `Перевожу комплексное число в вещественную.` - это ещё зачем?

Comment: вопросы не помогают